# how to customize google compute engine sftp path?

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, sftp

I have configured **sftp** for my **google compute engine VM instance** by key method.

I had generated a private and public key by Puttykey generator tool. Then i add that public key to my vm instance path `/home/xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Now i can connected this sftp by Filezilla to this path. But i want to connect sftp directly to the following path

```
/home/xxx/yyy/zzz/
```

How can i change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Filezilla client usage issue.

Open FileZilla, go to Site Manager, and select the settings for your server. On the Advanced tab, the "Default remote directory" box specifies what folder your SFTP connection opens by default. Enter your /home/xxx/yyy/zzz/ in that box.